# Can a 100' string of led lights be powered from each end hooked to one power supply

Tags: led

can both ends of a 100' strip of leds be hooked to the same power supply with out damaging the power supply of leds

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We'll need a lot more information to help you, and this may not even be on topic here. For instance, it sounds like you're talking about LED strips powered by a LED-specific power supply; if so, then it completely depends on the specs for the LED strips and the power supply.

Comment: Yes, that’s a common trick to counter voltage drop.  Don’t mix which conductor is which. Simple ring topography for power feed.

Comment: Adafruit uses the technique in several tutorials.  I'm having trouble finding one that addresses your need EXACTLY, most deal with multiple 10 meter strips. As long as you keep + and - sorted tho you can feed from the same power supply to both ends, don't do it with the data line(s) tho.

Comment: I've done it with slotcar tracks. :P

Comment: Any trolley modeler has done it with trolley tracks :) as do real trolley systems.  You can feeder with DC.

Answer (score 1):

120V or any mains voltage - no no no no no no no!

5 or 12 volt DC, yes, and at 100' you will need to feed it from ***many*** intermediate points as well.

24 volt DC, along 100 feet you will not only need to feed both ends but several intermediate points too.  Just not as many as 12V.